# Decide to create a new item or update an old one in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have two methods, in one I create a new list item, in the second I update the current list item.

```
private fun addTarget() {
    val name = nameEditText?.text.toString().trim()
    val description = descriptionEditText?.text.toString().trim()

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
        val id: String = databaseReference?.push()?.key.toString()
        val target = Target(guid = id, name = name, description = description)
        databaseReference?.child(id)?.setValue(target)
    } else Log.d("some", "Enter a name")
}

private fun updateTarget() {
    val name = nameEditText?.text.toString().trim()
    val description = descriptionEditText?.text.toString().trim()

    val map = mapOf("name" to name, "description" to description)
    databaseReference?.child(arguments?.getString(KEY_TARGET_GUID, "") ?: "")?.updateChildren(map)
}
```

I need to clearly separate these two concepts, so there is a problem in the condition.

```
button?.setOnClickListener { if (condition?????) addTarget() else updateTarget() }
```

For example, in the Realm there is a method `copyToRealmOrUpdate` which looks for the `field` and if it finds it *updates* it if not then *creates a new* note. How can I do something like this in firebase?

I resolved my problem next:
When I go to the fragment I pass the `guid` from the list of all elements and if it is empty then I add if not then update.

```
button?.setOnClickListener {
        if (arguments?.getString(KEY_TARGET_GUID, "").isNullOrEmpty()) addTarget()
        else updateTarget()
    }
```

I don't know how this is a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in Firebase if you are using `exist()` method like in the following lines of code:

```
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            //Do the update
        } else {
            //Do the addition
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
databaseReference.child("-LaVYDBpwiIcwhe9qz2H").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Comment: Updated question, can u check please my solution? What do you think of it?

Comment: No, you should first check in the database for the existens of the element.

Comment: Have you solved the issue, can I help you with other informations?